# Custom categories for the favorites Questions

Tags: feature-request

Since my favorite Questions are growing and growing, it would be nice, if we can create categories for our favourites Questions.

For example I often add new interesting Questions into my favorite list, to see the results later. If I could assign this to a categorie **"Check back later"**, it would be more easy to find them again.

Comment: Bookmarks are well suited for this.